# Running maven plugin from command line outside pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, snyk

Below is the snyk plugin setup for maven. I have setup the plugin in `pom.xml`. I configured the maven set up in a pipeline. The below configuration has a secret `API_TOKEN`. Setting `API_TOKEN` as a variable in any file except the default pipeline file does not work. So I am exploring some way to setup and run the plugin in pipeline file i.e. to access and run plugin in mvn commandline for example
`mvn my-plugin:my-goal -Dplugin.property=ABC`.

But I am not sure, how to call snyk plugin and run during build/install/deploy command.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.snyk</groupId>
                <artifactId>snyk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>snyk-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>snyk-monitor</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>monitor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <apiToken>${SNYK_TOKEN}</apiToken>
                    <failOnSeverity>high</failOnSeverity>
                    <org>MDA</org>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. You can run any plugin on command line (in the way you stated), but then it will not be part of the lifecycle, i.e. not part of any phase like install or deploy.

Comment: It's ok, if it is not part of any lifecycle phase

Answer (score 0):

The team just released a new version of the plugin. This is the [github repo](https://github.com/snyk/snyk-maven-plugin/).

Example

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.snyk</groupId>
      <artifactId>snyk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>snyk-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>snyk-monitor</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>monitor</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <apiToken>${env.SNYK_TOKEN}</apiToken>
        <args>
          <arg>--all-projects</arg>
        </args>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

By default now the `snyk-test` is linked to the `mvn test`. The `monitor` is connected to the `mvn install` phase by default. Obviously, you can change this like below.

```
<executions>
   <execution>
       <phase>verify</phase>
       <id>snyk-test</id>
       <goals>
           <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
   <execution>
       <phase>none</phase>
       <id>snyk-monitor</id>
       <goals>
           <goal>monitor</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

The API token in the first example is referring to an environment variable.

For more information maybe this [blog post](https://snyk.io/blog/snyk-maven-plugin-integrated-security-vulnerability-scanning-for-developers/) gives a more complete overview.